# AWS appsync graphql subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I have two seprate apps each has seprate AWS cognito userpool appsync api but has shared dynamodb. I want to create subscription for chat feature where app 1 (client app) and app 2 (admin app) will communicate. Is it possible please advise.
I have followed this article from aws:
[enter link description here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-a-full-stack-chat-application-with-aws-and-nextjs/)

need advise how would that work in my case with two different apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to take a step back and separate the problem from the technology. You want to create a chat app, how would you build this? Do you need a data store or a queue? First think in abstractions then look what technology fits those abstractions best. If you start with the technology first you will most likely end up with a sub-par solution.

If you really want to go for the technology first approach you could think of storing chats in DynamoDB(DDB) and using [DDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) to update the subscription. It can work but it will most likely be expensive.